# With a ./configure (php) what is the difference between --disable-[name] and --without-[name]?

Tags: php, autoconf, configure

I want to avoid compiling php with fileinfo, ereg, and parch. What is the difference between --disable and --without with configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [**the manual of Autoconf**](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html), and, more specifically, the two following sections :

- [15.2 Working With External Software](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#External-Software)
- and [15.3 Choosing Package Options](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Package-Options)

`--with` should be used if a package requires, or can optionally use, other software that is already installed.

And `--enable` should be used if a package provides some feature, without depending on any other external software.

Basically, I suppose it means that `--with` should be used for extensions that depend on another external library ; and that `--enable` should be used in the other situations.

After that, I'd say that `--disable` and `--without` are just the negative form of those two.